# ¿Puedo eliminar una posición de un ArrayList si el String que contiene dicha posición coincide con una palabra?

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

Tengo un ArrayList de String que tiene varios valores. Mi idea es, si es posible, que si una palabra que yo le paso al ArrayList pueda coincidir con los valores que almacena el ArrayList para eliminar la posición en la que lo contiene.
Yo tengo este código, donde utilizo un if y .contains para ver si la palabra que le paso se encuentra en el ArrayList, ahora lo que quisiera es que se eliminase dicha posición. Estoy probando de varias formas pero no me funciona.

```
        if(listFilasRu.contains("Jose"){
           listFilasRu.remove("13;Hombre;Jose");
           listFilasRu.remove("Jose");
        }
```

¿Sería posible realizar esta acción? Gracias.

Comment: podes hacer uso del metodo removeIf  `listFilasRu.removeIf(p->p.contains("Jose"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la lista te permite modificarla podrias usar el metodo `removeIf` directo.

```
listFilasRu.removeIf(s -> s.equals("Jose"));
```

Si no te permite modificarla tienes 2 opciones:

- Crear una nueva lista a partir de la existente y remover

```
 List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(listFilasRu);
 newList.removeIf(s -> s.equals("Jose"));
```

- Filtrar la lista por o los elementos que quieres remover

```
List<String> newList = listFilasRu.stream()
        .filter(s -> !s.equals("Jose"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Buenas, he cambiado el s.equals("Jose") por s.contains("Jose") y parece que así funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Yo siempre realizo un método buscar que me devuelva null si no encuentra el objeto o que me devuelva el objeto en si, si es que lo encuentra.
Si lo encuentra, y ya tengo el objeto (en tu caso, el String), uso ArrayList.remove(objeto).

**Te paso como sería el buscar:**

```
public static String buscarString(String stringABuscar) {
        int pos = 0;
        String stringBuscado = null;
        while (pos <= arrayDeStrings.size() && arrayDeStrings.get(pos).equals(stringABuscar)) {
            pos++;
        }
        if (pos < arrayDeStrings.size()) {
            stringBuscado = stringABuscar;
        }
        return stringBuscado;
    }
```

**Y cómo quedaria en el main:**

```
public static ArrayList<String> arrayDeStrings = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    arrayDeStrings.add("string en posición 0");
    arrayDeStrings.add("string en posición 1");
    arrayDeStrings.add("string en posición 2");

    if (buscarString("string en posición 1") != null) {
        arrayDeStrings.remove("string en posición 1");
    }
    
}
```

Corroboralo haciendo un System.out.println(arrayDeStrings.get(1)); y verás que ahora tenes el String que estaba en la posición dos porque se borró el objeto de la posición 1 y se modificó la lista.